# Add and Remove css file on button click react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an application in which I have two different css files for two totally different pages.

one.Component.js should include style1.css and two.Component.js should include style2.css

I have imported the css file separately in the component files. But when the components are loaded both the css gets conflicted and the page is collapsed.

one.Component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'style1.css';

export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div class="theme-color">Hi</div>
        )
    }
}
```

two.Component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'style2.css';

export default class ComponentTwo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div class="theme-color">Hi</div>
        )
    }
}
```

When this react application loads, both the css are loaded and hence there is a conflict.

Could any one help me out in getting the css file to load only when a particular page is rendered and not when the page is loaded.

Or it is possible to include one css files on button click and remove the other css files based on the component displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
import styles from "./style.css"
```

This will add random string to your classes, hence it becomes component scoped

Use styles example :

```
<button className={styles.button}>Button</button>
```

Code for your exact case

Component 1 :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import style from 'style1.css';

export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div className={style.theme-color}>Hi</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Component 2 :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import style from 'style2.css';

export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div className={style.theme-color}>Hi</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ZOthix. Thanks for your reply. I am trying your method in my code. Could you tell how to use two class names. Eg: <button className={style.btn + style.btn-default}> gives me error. Also, it throws error 'color' is not defined in 'style.theme-color'

Comment: Fixed the issue 'color' is not defined. Use className={style['theme-color']} in this way css class name with hypen can be used\

Comment: You can use  `className={ [style.btn,  style.btn-default] }`
Or ``className={ `${style.btn}  ${style.btn-default}` }``

Comment: If my answer solved the problem described in your question, kindly mark it as accepted answer so others can take benefit from it as well